# how to convert JSON array into JavaScript 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to convert the following JSON into a JS 2D array, but I am not sure how to do this in html.

```
[{"fields": {"diameter": 23.0, "neighbourhood": "WEST END"}, "model": "hug.tree", "pk": 345}, 
 {"fields": {"diameter": 14.0, "neighbourhood": "MOUNT PLEASANT"}, "model": "hug.tree", "pk": 484}]
```

The result should be something like:

```
[[23.0, 'WEST END'], [14.0, 'MOUNT PLEASANT']]
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Parse the JSON, iterate over the array and create a new one. What *exactly* are you having problems with? Do you know how to parse JSON? How to iterate over an array? How to access properties of objects? How to create an array? *"I am not sure how to do this in html"* HTML is not a programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work with all fields of "fields", not only for `diameter` or `neighborhood`.

**Demo**:

```js
var items = [{"fields": {"diameter": 23.0, "neighbourhood": "WEST END"}, "model": "hug.tree", "pk": 345}, {"fields": {"diameter": 14.0, "neighbourhood": "MOUNT PLEASANT"}, "model": "hug.tree", "pk": 484}];

var i = 0, result = [];

while(i < items.length){
    result.push([])
    for(var key in items[i].fields){
        result[result.length-1].push(items[i].fields[key]) 
    }
    i++
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

For each item in `json` push a new array with the `diameter` and `neighborhood` into a result array.

```
var json = [{"fields": {"diameter": 23.0, "neighbourhood": "WEST END"}, "model": "hug.tree", "pk": 345}, {"fields": {"diameter": 14.0, "neighbourhood": "MOUNT PLEASANT"}, "model": "hug.tree", "pk": 484}];
var done = [];
json.forEach(function(object){
    done.push([object.fields.diameter,object.fields.neighbourhood]);
});

console.log(done);
```