# Datatables - how to get columns of dataSrc

Tags: jquery, datatables

So my backend is returning

```
[{"id":"371","ref":"35\/2016","creator":"Name","status":"part1","username":"user","date":"2016-12-14 00:00:00","title":null,"site":null,"location":"","comment":null}]
```

I saw `dataSrc : ""` being used in an example, but in this example: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html they conveniently don't make an example of how to get it when they're an array of objects.

Any tips on how to use the `columns: [...]` working will be appreciated.

Comment: You mean : `[{}, {}, {}]`?

Comment: @MYGz I only need 3 of the objects stuff. I've tried `{ id: "id" }` and `{ data : "id" }` but they don't work, so I'm a bit lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was because I didn't properly initialise the DataTable. But I also found an example here: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_flat.html

So you still just use "data" in the columns key.

https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_flat.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "url": "data/objects_root_array.txt",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link. https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects_subarrays.html

See the ajax tab (below) to see what the server is returning.

Using the columns was also used. But for more information, see https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data

**EDIT:**
Modify your ajax request like this

```
"ajax": {
            "url" : "",
            "dataSrc" : function (object){
                return object.data;
            }
        }
```

Comment: if you look at the ajax part of the file it has `data: {...}` which is what I don't have.

Comment: May i know what you are using to get your data?

Comment: I believe that would just be fine. Just make sure your object would be exactly the same as you column data reference. (ie. {"data" : "id"}, {"data":"ref"}, ...)

Comment: just the `ajax` part. I got another part working that has the `data` part in place. So basically I just have `ajax: {url: "some url"}`

Comment: Add "dataSrc": function(object){return object.data;} after you "url" : "some url" (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 :**
Have a look [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html) I think this is your answer.

**Method 2 :**
You can Parse your json response and create an multidimention array and pass it into datasrc
[how to convert JSON array into JavaScript 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825129/how-to-convert-json-array-into-javascript-2d-array)

**Method 3 :**
You can Parse your response and create a table structure something like below and append it into a div :

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Extn.</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Name xyz</td>
<td>Position xyz</td>
<td>Office xyz</td>
<td>Extn xyz</td>
<td>05-Jan-2017</td>
<td>10lacs</td>
</tr>
<tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Extn.</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

Now apply jquery code like below

```
$('#example').DataTable({
                responsive: true,
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                ]
     });
```

Comment: Will investigate a bit later